# Context: How to hide list of floats if it's empty (there are no floats)?

Tags: table-of-contents, context

Is there a way to make `\completelistoffigures`and `\completelistoffloats` only create their lists when list is not empty?

**Edit**: see [Fran's comment below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563229/context-how-to-hide-list-of-floats-if-its-empty-there-are-no-floats?noredirect=1#comment1420693_563229) for a solution regarding ConTeXt via Pandoc.

I use ConTeXt via [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf), to convert from Markdown to PDF. Here is a small example, a little different from my setup but still with same problem:

With a command like

```bash
pandoc -f markdown -t context -V lof -V lot -o test.tex test.md
# convert from markdown to context,
# with variables 'list of figures' and 'list of tables' set as true,
# to output file test.tex and from input file test.md
```

and for `test.md` with one image and *no table at all*, following file (excerpt) is generated:

```tex
...
\setupfloat[figure][default={here,nonumber}]
\setupfloat[table][default={here,nonumber}]
...
\setupxtable[frame=off]
\setupxtable[head][topframe=on,bottomframe=on]
\setupxtable[body][]
\setupxtable[foot][bottomframe=on]

\starttext
\completelistoftables
\completelistoffigures
...
```

As input file has one image, list of figures is placed correctly. But as there are no tables in document, `\completelistoftables` generates a list with only its title. What I want is **completely hide this list if there are no tables in document** (substitute "tables" with figures or any other floats). How can I accomplish that?

Looking in wiki and manuals, I've only figured out about `criterium` parameter, but it does nothing in this case.

(I know I could simply remove `\completelistoftables`, or even `lot` variable in Pandoc, but this would remove the generic nature of the template... And there are solved questions about this, but all of them are about *LaTeX*, not *ConTeXt*)

Comment: Via pandoc from where? markdown? What variables are you using? Are you using a custom template? Without a simple example to test is only guessing, but omit the variable lof  in the command line or set `lof: no` in the YALM header should be enough, although other possibility is customize the `default.context` template.

Comment: @Fran thanks for answer. I've edited question with a small example, with default template and minimal commands: still problem occurs. As I said initially in the question, simply removing the command is *not* what I'm asking, as I use this setup with other documents as well.

Comment: The YALM headers are precisely for document-specific options, i.e, If you have to use a single pandoc command and a single template usable for documents with or without figures , the solution is not `-V lof` in the command line but specify  `lof: yes`  or `lof: no` in the YAML header of each .md file. With the same approach for `lot` variable, the pandoc command could be reduced to simply  `pandoc  -t context -o test.tex test.md` and the result must be fine in every case.

Comment: Thank you, @Fran, I didn't figure out that! It works! (By the way, the example command I wrote in question is not what I use. I'm using Pandoc default files, which greatly simplify my command)

Comment: @Fran Could you post your comment as an answer.